# what is best way to indentify that the length of tuple in a list is 0 using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some list. Each list has some tuples. I want to process (print the value of my tuple). But some of my list has some tuples which is the length of all tuples is 0. I want to identify that i can past that list for next process because there is no value in my tuples.

Example:

```
myList1= [(),(1,2),(2,3)]
myList2= [(),(),(),()]
myList3= [(),(),()]

def Check_true_List(myList):
    r = 0
    for x in myList:
      if len(x) != 0:
        r+=1
    return r != 0

if Check_true_List(myList2):
   for t in myList2:
      for value in t:
        print value
```

my `Check_true_List` is working well as I want, But, is there another way to identify that the length of all tuples in my list is not 0 ?? I think my way (function: `Check_true_List`) is not effective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the `any()` function:

```
>>> myList1= [(),(1,2),(2,3)]
>>> myList2= [(),(),(),()]
>>> myList3= [(),(),()]
>>> any(myList1)
True
>>> any(myList2)
False
>>> any(myList3)
False
```

Comment: Thank you. I will use your answer :)